# Mozilla Firefox: SVG image is not working in dialog using 6.2 environement

Tags: javascript, svg, aem

I've create a Image component which will allow to drag and drop only svg images, so far its working fine but the problem is, some svg images are not supported in Mozilla browser but the same is working fine in Chrome browser.

While drag and drop the svg image in dialog, the changes will happen but svg image is not visible in dialog once dialog submitted, i can see the image in browser but i want to know why some svg images are visible in dialog.
[image]
Please suggest what is the solution for this?

SVG CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 230.3 192.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 230.3 192.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M104.5,107.9c0,5-4,9-9,9s-9-4-9-9s4-9,9-9h0.1C100.5,98.9,104.5,102.9,104.5,107.9z M136.4,98.9L136.4,98.9c-5,0-9,4-9,9
    s4.1,9,9,9s9-4,9-9S141.4,98.9,136.4,98.9z M136.4,140.1L136.4,140.1c-5,0-9,4-9,9s4.1,9,9,9s9-4,9-9S141.4,140.1,136.4,140.1z
     M95.5,140.1L95.5,140.1c-5,0-9,4-9,9s4.1,9,9,9s9-4,9-9S100.5,140.1,95.5,140.1z M229.3,86.5c0,13.1-10.7,23.7-23.7,23.7h-14.3
    v55.6c0,14.6-11.8,26.4-26.4,26.4H67c-14.6,0-26.4-11.8-26.4-26.4v-55.6H26.3c-13.1,0-23.7-10.6-23.7-23.7c0-18.3,5-34.2,15-47.2
    C25.7,28.6,37.1,20,51.5,13.9C73.6,4.3,98.4,2.3,115.3,2.3c13.8,0,40.6,1.5,64.4,11.7c14.5,6.2,26,14.7,34.3,25.4
    C224.2,52.4,229.3,68.2,229.3,86.5z M175.3,165.8v-55.7c-12.3-0.8-22-10.6-22-22.5c0-8.3-2.4-11.3-4.7-13.1
    c-3.9-3.1-12.8-6.8-33.2-6.8c-9,0-25.1,0.9-32.2,6.8c-2.2,1.8-4.4,4.8-4.4,13c0,11.9-9.7,21.7-22,22.5v55.7
    c0,5.7,4.7,10.4,10.4,10.4h97.8C170.6,176.2,175.3,171.5,175.3,165.8z M213.3,86.5c0-63.1-73.7-68.2-98.1-68.2
    c-24.4,0-96.7,4.6-96.7,68.1c0,4.3,3.5,7.7,7.7,7.7H55c3.8,0,7.7-2.7,7.7-6.6c0-19.6,9.4-35.9,52.6-35.9c43.2,0,53.9,15.4,53.9,35.9
    c0,3.8,3.9,6.6,7.7,6.6h28.7C209.8,94.2,213.3,90.8,213.3,86.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: First, the correct mime type is ‘image/svg+xml’. second, the issue might just be that the SVG that isnt working has some issues (xml not parsable by firefox for some reason). Please share the xml for the svg that is NOT working on firefox so we can help you further.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, added svg XML code

Comment: I dont think problem is in SVG image because its working in preview mode, the image is not visible in dialog only

Comment: can you inspect the dialog in firefox console and post it’s HTML? The issue is probably a rouge css rule (there are a few known issues with firefox)

Comment: Oh wait, you said it happens for some SVG but others work in the dialog on firefox? If so, your last option is to inspect in firefox console and remove css rules/classes one-by-one until it’s fixed.

Comment: I removed all css rules but it is not visible, because some extjs or AEM dialog features is not supported

Comment: its not an css related issues

Comment: `because some extjs or AEM dialog features is not supported` What does that mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173863/discussion-between-jinfy-and-ahmed-musallam).